# Python is adding to dictionary value of a key that is not being accessed

Tags: python, dictionary

My python program is adding data to a key that is not being accessed. I am accessing a key called "one_week" who's value is a dictionary. However when modifying the data in "one_week", the data in another key in the same dictionary as "one_week" is also being modified.

I have this data:

```py
performance = {
 '2022-05-25': {'basicMaterialsChangesPercentage': 0.5966,
                'communicationServicesChangesPercentage': 2.2651,
                'conglomeratesChangesPercentage': 0,
                'consumerCyclicalChangesPercentage': 3.5155,
                'consumerDefensiveChangesPercentage': 1.2746,
                'energyChangesPercentage': 2.6591,
                'financialChangesPercentage': -0.3344,
                'financialServicesChangesPercentage': 0.7993,
                'healthcareChangesPercentage': 0.1801,
                'industrialsChangesPercentage': 1.5138,
                'realEstateChangesPercentage': 1.0937,
                'servicesChangesPercentage': 0,
                'technologyChangesPercentage': 2.2088,
                'utilitiesChangesPercentage': 0.7255},
 '2022-05-26': {'basicMaterialsChangesPercentage': 1.694,
                'communicationServicesChangesPercentage': 2.3833,
                'conglomeratesChangesPercentage': 0,
                'consumerCyclicalChangesPercentage': 3.7358,
                'consumerDefensiveChangesPercentage': 1.7021,
                'energyChangesPercentage': 1.6321,
                'financialChangesPercentage': 2.181,
                'financialServicesChangesPercentage': 1.0564,
                'healthcareChangesPercentage': 1.1553,
                'industrialsChangesPercentage': 2.021,
                'realEstateChangesPercentage': 0.9909,
                'servicesChangesPercentage': 0,
                'technologyChangesPercentage': 2.489,
                'utilitiesChangesPercentage': 0.3186},
 '2022-05-27': {'basicMaterialsChangesPercentage': 1.8731,
                'communicationServicesChangesPercentage': 1.8654,
                'conglomeratesChangesPercentage': 0,
                'consumerCyclicalChangesPercentage': 2.3831,
                'consumerDefensiveChangesPercentage': 1.749,
                'energyChangesPercentage': 1.9711,
                'financialChangesPercentage': 0.5423,
                'financialServicesChangesPercentage': 1.0966,
                'healthcareChangesPercentage': 3.053,
                'industrialsChangesPercentage': 2.187,
                'realEstateChangesPercentage': 1.7737,
                'servicesChangesPercentage': 0,
                'technologyChangesPercentage': 3.3629,
                'utilitiesChangesPercentage': 1.1453},
 '2022-05-28': {'basicMaterialsChangesPercentage': 1.8731,
                'communicationServicesChangesPercentage': 1.8654,
                'conglomeratesChangesPercentage': 0,
                'consumerCyclicalChangesPercentage': 2.3831,
                'consumerDefensiveChangesPercentage': 1.749,
                'energyChangesPercentage': 1.9711,
                'financialChangesPercentage': 0.5423,
                'financialServicesChangesPercentage': 1.0966,
                'healthcareChangesPercentage': 3.053,
                'industrialsChangesPercentage': 2.187,
                'realEstateChangesPercentage': 1.7769,
                'servicesChangesPercentage': 0,
                'technologyChangesPercentage': 3.3629,
                'utilitiesChangesPercentage': 1.1453},
 '2022-05-30': {'basicMaterialsChangesPercentage': 1.8397,
                'communicationServicesChangesPercentage': 1.9118,
                'conglomeratesChangesPercentage': 0,
                'consumerCyclicalChangesPercentage': 2.3831,
                'consumerDefensiveChangesPercentage': 1.749,
                'energyChangesPercentage': 1.9711,
                'financialChangesPercentage': 0.5423,
                'financialServicesChangesPercentage': 1.0953,
                'healthcareChangesPercentage': 3.053,
                'industrialsChangesPercentage': 2.187,
                'realEstateChangesPercentage': 1.7737,
                'servicesChangesPercentage': 0,
                'technologyChangesPercentage': 3.3629,
                'utilitiesChangesPercentage': 1.1453},
 '2022-05-31': {'basicMaterialsChangesPercentage': -1.8391,
                'communicationServicesChangesPercentage': -0.72,
                'conglomeratesChangesPercentage': 0,
                'consumerCyclicalChangesPercentage': -0.5211,
                'consumerDefensiveChangesPercentage': -0.2501,
                'energyChangesPercentage': -0.6778,
                'financialChangesPercentage': 0.7535,
                'financialServicesChangesPercentage': -0.1327,
                'healthcareChangesPercentage': -1.3749,
                'industrialsChangesPercentage': -0.6523,
                'realEstateChangesPercentage': -0.2081,
                'servicesChangesPercentage': 0,
                'technologyChangesPercentage': -1.0196,
                'utilitiesChangesPercentage': -0.8095},
 '2022-06-01': {'basicMaterialsChangesPercentage': -0.6145,
                'communicationServicesChangesPercentage': -1.019,
                'conglomeratesChangesPercentage': 0,
                'consumerCyclicalChangesPercentage': -1.3616,
                'consumerDefensiveChangesPercentage': -1.3518,
                'energyChangesPercentage': 2.0396,
                'financialChangesPercentage': -0.5411,
                'financialServicesChangesPercentage': -0.3852,
                'healthcareChangesPercentage': -2.302,
                'industrialsChangesPercentage': -0.4424,
                'realEstateChangesPercentage': -0.1271,
                'servicesChangesPercentage': 0,
                'technologyChangesPercentage': -1.0108,
                'utilitiesChangesPercentage': -0.3783},
 '2022-06-02': {'basicMaterialsChangesPercentage': 3.4834,
                'communicationServicesChangesPercentage': 1.7224,
                'conglomeratesChangesPercentage': 0,
                'consumerCyclicalChangesPercentage': 2.7236,
                'consumerDefensiveChangesPercentage': 1.6454,
                'energyChangesPercentage': 0.5619,
                'financialChangesPercentage': 0.6452,
                'financialServicesChangesPercentage': 0.7528,
                'healthcareChangesPercentage': 2.1004,
                'industrialsChangesPercentage': 2.3525,
                'realEstateChangesPercentage': 0.669,
                'servicesChangesPercentage': 0,
                'technologyChangesPercentage': 3.3993,
                'utilitiesChangesPercentage': 1.1764},
 '2022-06-03': {'basicMaterialsChangesPercentage': -1.5836,
                'communicationServicesChangesPercentage': -1.581,
                'conglomeratesChangesPercentage': 0,
                'consumerCyclicalChangesPercentage': -1.6655,
                'consumerDefensiveChangesPercentage': -0.5413,
                'energyChangesPercentage': 0.9082,
                'financialChangesPercentage': -1.197,
                'financialServicesChangesPercentage': -0.6514,
                'healthcareChangesPercentage': 0.5676,
                'industrialsChangesPercentage': -0.6715,
                'realEstateChangesPercentage': -0.8244,
                'servicesChangesPercentage': 0,
                'technologyChangesPercentage': -1.7852,
                'utilitiesChangesPercentage': -0.3472},
 '2022-06-04': {'basicMaterialsChangesPercentage': -1.5836,
                'communicationServicesChangesPercentage': -1.581,
                'conglomeratesChangesPercentage': 0,
                'consumerCyclicalChangesPercentage': -1.6655,
                'consumerDefensiveChangesPercentage': -0.5413,
                'energyChangesPercentage': 0.9082,
                'financialChangesPercentage': -1.197,
                'financialServicesChangesPercentage': -0.6514,
                'healthcareChangesPercentage': 0.5676,
                'industrialsChangesPercentage': -0.6715,
                'realEstateChangesPercentage': -0.8244,
                'servicesChangesPercentage': 0,
                'technologyChangesPercentage': -1.7852,
                'utilitiesChangesPercentage': -0.3472},
 '2022-06-06': {'basicMaterialsChangesPercentage': 0.0809,
                'communicationServicesChangesPercentage': -0.4309,
                'conglomeratesChangesPercentage': 0,
                'consumerCyclicalChangesPercentage': 0.3418,
                'consumerDefensiveChangesPercentage': 0.2364,
                'energyChangesPercentage': 0.1332,
                'financialChangesPercentage': 0.863,
                'financialServicesChangesPercentage': 0.0877,
                'healthcareChangesPercentage': -2.3642,
                'industrialsChangesPercentage': 0.6835,
                'realEstateChangesPercentage': -0.2208,
                'servicesChangesPercentage': 0,
                'technologyChangesPercentage': -0.0487,
                'utilitiesChangesPercentage': -0.032},
 '2022-06-07': {'basicMaterialsChangesPercentage': 0.6928,
                'communicationServicesChangesPercentage': 0.6454,
                'conglomeratesChangesPercentage': 0,
                'consumerCyclicalChangesPercentage': 0.6169,
                'consumerDefensiveChangesPercentage': 0.3133,
                'energyChangesPercentage': 2.9692,
                'financialChangesPercentage': 0.8556,
                'financialServicesChangesPercentage': 0.1918,
                'healthcareChangesPercentage': 3.0295,
                'industrialsChangesPercentage': 0.7845,
                'realEstateChangesPercentage': 0.806,
                'servicesChangesPercentage': 0,
                'technologyChangesPercentage': 0.7692,
                'utilitiesChangesPercentage': 0.0621},
 '2022-06-08': {'basicMaterialsChangesPercentage': -1.1986,
                'communicationServicesChangesPercentage': 0.1896,
                'conglomeratesChangesPercentage': 0,
                'consumerCyclicalChangesPercentage': -0.1521,
                'consumerDefensiveChangesPercentage': 0.0894,
                'energyChangesPercentage': -0.5774,
                'financialChangesPercentage': -1.9629,
                'financialServicesChangesPercentage': -0.629,
                'healthcareChangesPercentage': 0.4692,
                'industrialsChangesPercentage': -1.4459,
                'realEstateChangesPercentage': -1.288,
                'servicesChangesPercentage': 0,
                'technologyChangesPercentage': -0.6647,
                'utilitiesChangesPercentage': -1.063},
 '2022-06-09': {'basicMaterialsChangesPercentage': -3.0877,
                'communicationServicesChangesPercentage': -2.38,
                'conglomeratesChangesPercentage': 0,
                'consumerCyclicalChangesPercentage': -2.2434,
                'consumerDefensiveChangesPercentage': -1.9428,
                'energyChangesPercentage': -2.5797,
                'financialChangesPercentage': -2.1158,
                'financialServicesChangesPercentage': -1.1578,
                'healthcareChangesPercentage': -2.6882,
                'industrialsChangesPercentage': -2.1356,
                'realEstateChangesPercentage': -1.7272,
                'servicesChangesPercentage': 0,
                'technologyChangesPercentage': -3.392,
                'utilitiesChangesPercentage': -2.4094},
 '2022-06-10': {'basicMaterialsChangesPercentage': -0.8835,
                'communicationServicesChangesPercentage': -2.7662,
                'conglomeratesChangesPercentage': 0,
                'consumerCyclicalChangesPercentage': -3.9916,
                'consumerDefensiveChangesPercentage': -1.7072,
                'energyChangesPercentage': -1.6846,
                'financialChangesPercentage': -2.4166,
                'financialServicesChangesPercentage': -1.3287,
                'healthcareChangesPercentage': -4.0447,
                'industrialsChangesPercentage': -2.9806,
                'realEstateChangesPercentage': -1.9476,
                'servicesChangesPercentage': 0,
                'technologyChangesPercentage': -3.4835,
                'utilitiesChangesPercentage': -1.4438},
 '2022-06-11': {'basicMaterialsChangesPercentage': -0.8835,
                'communicationServicesChangesPercentage': -2.7662,
                'conglomeratesChangesPercentage': 0,
                'consumerCyclicalChangesPercentage': -3.9916,
                'consumerDefensiveChangesPercentage': -1.7072,
                'energyChangesPercentage': -1.6846,
                'financialChangesPercentage': -2.4166,
                'financialServicesChangesPercentage': -1.3287,
                'healthcareChangesPercentage': -4.0447,
                'industrialsChangesPercentage': -2.9806,
                'realEstateChangesPercentage': -1.9607,
                'servicesChangesPercentage': 0,
                'technologyChangesPercentage': -3.4835,
                'utilitiesChangesPercentage': -1.4438},
 '2022-06-13': {'basicMaterialsChangesPercentage': -6.0283,
                'communicationServicesChangesPercentage': -5.8389,
                'conglomeratesChangesPercentage': 0,
                'consumerCyclicalChangesPercentage': -6.1994,
                'consumerDefensiveChangesPercentage': -4.1023,
                'energyChangesPercentage': -6.7057,
                'financialChangesPercentage': -5.8465,
                'financialServicesChangesPercentage': -2.5436,
                'healthcareChangesPercentage': -5.8052,
                'industrialsChangesPercentage': -4.9893,
                'realEstateChangesPercentage': -5.4045,
                'servicesChangesPercentage': 0,
                'technologyChangesPercentage': -6.3218,
                'utilitiesChangesPercentage': -5.0062},
 '2022-06-14': {'basicMaterialsChangesPercentage': -0.9762,
                'communicationServicesChangesPercentage': -0.7266,
                'conglomeratesChangesPercentage': 0,
                'consumerCyclicalChangesPercentage': -0.079,
                'consumerDefensiveChangesPercentage': 0.5071,
                'energyChangesPercentage': -1.5016,
                'financialChangesPercentage': -4.3202,
                'financialServicesChangesPercentage': -0.3531,
                'healthcareChangesPercentage': -0.7608,
                'industrialsChangesPercentage': -0.5548,
                'realEstateChangesPercentage': -1.217,
                'servicesChangesPercentage': 0,
                'technologyChangesPercentage': -0.376,
                'utilitiesChangesPercentage': -1.5321},
 '2022-06-15': {'basicMaterialsChangesPercentage': 1.2233,
                'communicationServicesChangesPercentage': 2.6448,
                'conglomeratesChangesPercentage': 0,
                'consumerCyclicalChangesPercentage': 1.9838,
                'consumerDefensiveChangesPercentage': 1.8249,
                'energyChangesPercentage': -0.0898,
                'financialChangesPercentage': 1.2547,
                'financialServicesChangesPercentage': 0.5181,
                'healthcareChangesPercentage': 1.7891,
                'industrialsChangesPercentage': 1.5349,
                'realEstateChangesPercentage': 1.5974,
                'servicesChangesPercentage': 0,
                'technologyChangesPercentage': 2.387,
                'utilitiesChangesPercentage': 1.3948},
 '2022-06-16': {'basicMaterialsChangesPercentage': -3.4558,
                'communicationServicesChangesPercentage': -4.5108,
                'conglomeratesChangesPercentage': 0,
                'consumerCyclicalChangesPercentage': -6.0633,
                'consumerDefensiveChangesPercentage': -2.1755,
                'energyChangesPercentage': -4.881,
                'financialChangesPercentage': -3.9113,
                'financialServicesChangesPercentage': -2.1979,
                'healthcareChangesPercentage': -3.2739,
                'industrialsChangesPercentage': -4.8727,
                'realEstateChangesPercentage': -3.0626,
                'servicesChangesPercentage': 0,
                'technologyChangesPercentage': -4.849,
                'utilitiesChangesPercentage': -1.6436},
 '2022-06-17': {'basicMaterialsChangesPercentage': -0.6707,
                'communicationServicesChangesPercentage': 1.5904,
                'conglomeratesChangesPercentage': 0,
                'consumerCyclicalChangesPercentage': 2.1271,
                'consumerDefensiveChangesPercentage': 0.8003,
                'energyChangesPercentage': -4.5986,
                'financialChangesPercentage': -0.6562,
                'financialServicesChangesPercentage': 0.4154,
                'healthcareChangesPercentage': 2.3434,
                'industrialsChangesPercentage': 0.5374,
                'realEstateChangesPercentage': 1.2594,
                'servicesChangesPercentage': 0,
                'technologyChangesPercentage': 2.3738,
                'utilitiesChangesPercentage': -0.3293},
 '2022-06-18': {'basicMaterialsChangesPercentage': -0.6707,
                'communicationServicesChangesPercentage': 1.5904,
                'conglomeratesChangesPercentage': 0,
                'consumerCyclicalChangesPercentage': 2.1271,
                'consumerDefensiveChangesPercentage': 0.8003,
                'energyChangesPercentage': -4.5986,
                'financialChangesPercentage': -0.6562,
                'financialServicesChangesPercentage': 0.4154,
                'healthcareChangesPercentage': 2.3434,
                'industrialsChangesPercentage': 0.5374,
                'realEstateChangesPercentage': 1.2594,
                'servicesChangesPercentage': 0,
                'technologyChangesPercentage': 2.3738,
                'utilitiesChangesPercentage': -0.3293}}
```

This is the code:

```py
req = requests.get(self.sector_performance).json()
performance = {}
for day in req:
    performance[day.get('date')] = {}
    for item in day:
        if item != 'date':
            performance[day.get('date')][item] = day.get(item)
            if performance[day.get('date')][item] == None:
                performance[day.get('date')][item] = 0
today = datetime.date.today()
average_performance = {'one_day': {}, 'one_week': {}, 'two_week': {}, 'one_month': {}}
for i in range(len(performance)):
    str_today = str(today)
    if i == 0:
        average_performance['one_day'] = performance.get(str_today)
        average_performance['one_week'] = performance.get(str_today)
        average_performance['two_week'] = performance.get(str_today)
        average_performance['one_month'] = performance.get(str_today)
        print(average_performance)
    if i < 5:
        for item in performance.get(str_today):
            average_performance['one_week'][item] += performance[str_today][item]
            print(average_performance)
```

This is the first two lines of output from the print statements:

```
{'one_day': {'basicMaterialsChangesPercentage': -0.6707,
             'communicationServicesChangesPercentage': 1.5904,
             'conglomeratesChangesPercentage': 0,
             'consumerCyclicalChangesPercentage': 2.1271,
             'consumerDefensiveChangesPercentage': 0.8003,
             'energyChangesPercentage': -4.5986,
             'financialChangesPercentage': -0.6562,
             'financialServicesChangesPercentage': 0.4154,
             'healthcareChangesPercentage': 2.3434,
             'industrialsChangesPercentage': 0.5374,
             'realEstateChangesPercentage': 1.2594,
             'servicesChangesPercentage': 0,
             'technologyChangesPercentage': 2.3738,
             'utilitiesChangesPercentage': -0.3293},
 'one_month': {'basicMaterialsChangesPercentage': -0.6707,
               'communicationServicesChangesPercentage': 1.5904,
               'conglomeratesChangesPercentage': 0,
               'consumerCyclicalChangesPercentage': 2.1271,
               'consumerDefensiveChangesPercentage': 0.8003,
               'energyChangesPercentage': -4.5986,
               'financialChangesPercentage': -0.6562,
               'financialServicesChangesPercentage': 0.4154,
               'healthcareChangesPercentage': 2.3434,
               'industrialsChangesPercentage': 0.5374,
               'realEstateChangesPercentage': 1.2594,
               'servicesChangesPercentage': 0,
               'technologyChangesPercentage': 2.3738,
               'utilitiesChangesPercentage': -0.3293},
 'one_week': {'basicMaterialsChangesPercentage': -0.6707,
              'communicationServicesChangesPercentage': 1.5904,
              'conglomeratesChangesPercentage': 0,
              'consumerCyclicalChangesPercentage': 2.1271,
              'consumerDefensiveChangesPercentage': 0.8003,
              'energyChangesPercentage': -4.5986,
              'financialChangesPercentage': -0.6562,
              'financialServicesChangesPercentage': 0.4154,
              'healthcareChangesPercentage': 2.3434,
              'industrialsChangesPercentage': 0.5374,
              'realEstateChangesPercentage': 1.2594,
              'servicesChangesPercentage': 0,
              'technologyChangesPercentage': 2.3738,
              'utilitiesChangesPercentage': -0.3293},
 'two_week': {'basicMaterialsChangesPercentage': -0.6707,
              'communicationServicesChangesPercentage': 1.5904,
              'conglomeratesChangesPercentage': 0,
              'consumerCyclicalChangesPercentage': 2.1271,
              'consumerDefensiveChangesPercentage': 0.8003,
              'energyChangesPercentage': -4.5986,
              'financialChangesPercentage': -0.6562,
              'financialServicesChangesPercentage': 0.4154,
              'healthcareChangesPercentage': 2.3434,
              'industrialsChangesPercentage': 0.5374,
              'realEstateChangesPercentage': 1.2594,
              'servicesChangesPercentage': 0,
              'technologyChangesPercentage': 2.3738,
              'utilitiesChangesPercentage': -0.3293}}
```

and

```
{'one_day': {'basicMaterialsChangesPercentage': -0.6707,
             'communicationServicesChangesPercentage': 1.5904,
             'conglomeratesChangesPercentage': 0,
             'consumerCyclicalChangesPercentage': 2.1271,
             'consumerDefensiveChangesPercentage': 0.8003,
             'energyChangesPercentage': -4.5986,
             'financialChangesPercentage': -0.6562,
             'financialServicesChangesPercentage': 0.4154,
             'healthcareChangesPercentage': 2.3434,
             'industrialsChangesPercentage': 0.5374,
             'realEstateChangesPercentage': 1.2594,
             'servicesChangesPercentage': 0,
             'technologyChangesPercentage': 2.3738,
             'utilitiesChangesPercentage': -0.6586},
 'one_month': {'basicMaterialsChangesPercentage': -0.6707,
               'communicationServicesChangesPercentage': 1.5904,
               'conglomeratesChangesPercentage': 0,
               'consumerCyclicalChangesPercentage': 2.1271,
               'consumerDefensiveChangesPercentage': 0.8003,
               'energyChangesPercentage': -4.5986,
               'financialChangesPercentage': -0.6562,
               'financialServicesChangesPercentage': 0.4154,
               'healthcareChangesPercentage': 2.3434,
               'industrialsChangesPercentage': 0.5374,
               'realEstateChangesPercentage': 1.2594,
               'servicesChangesPercentage': 0,
               'technologyChangesPercentage': 2.3738,
               'utilitiesChangesPercentage': -0.6586},
 'one_week': {'basicMaterialsChangesPercentage': -0.6707,
              'communicationServicesChangesPercentage': 1.5904,
              'conglomeratesChangesPercentage': 0,
              'consumerCyclicalChangesPercentage': 2.1271,
              'consumerDefensiveChangesPercentage': 0.8003,
              'energyChangesPercentage': -4.5986,
              'financialChangesPercentage': -0.6562,
              'financialServicesChangesPercentage': 0.4154,
              'healthcareChangesPercentage': 2.3434,
              'industrialsChangesPercentage': 0.5374,
              'realEstateChangesPercentage': 1.2594,
              'servicesChangesPercentage': 0,
              'technologyChangesPercentage': 2.3738,
              'utilitiesChangesPercentage': -0.6586},
 'two_week': {'basicMaterialsChangesPercentage': -0.6707,
              'communicationServicesChangesPercentage': 1.5904,
              'conglomeratesChangesPercentage': 0,
              'consumerCyclicalChangesPercentage': 2.1271,
              'consumerDefensiveChangesPercentage': 0.8003,
              'energyChangesPercentage': -4.5986,
              'financialChangesPercentage': -0.6562,
              'financialServicesChangesPercentage': 0.4154,
              'healthcareChangesPercentage': 2.3434,
              'industrialsChangesPercentage': 0.5374,
              'realEstateChangesPercentage': 1.2594,
              'servicesChangesPercentage': 0,
              'technologyChangesPercentage': 2.3738,
              'utilitiesChangesPercentage': -0.6586}}
```

From my understanding, the "one_day" key should not be modified after its first modification under the statement `if i == 0:`.  However, it is being modified under the statement `if i < 5:`.

Comment: First `if` is executed, then the next one, which also happens to be True... Maybe you mean `if/elif/else`?

Comment: Right, because if `i == 0`, then clearly `i < 5` is also true.

Comment: But i < 5 should only be modifying the values in the key "one_week", there is not code under the "i < 5" statement that is modifying the values in "one_day" @TimRoberts

Comment: When `i==0`, you are assigning THE SAME OBJECT to all four keys.  It's not 4 objects, it's not 4 copies, it's the same object.  When you modify one, you modify them all.  You probably need to use `copy`.

Comment: I want the same object to be assigned to all four keys when "i == 0" but I only want to modify the "one_week" after that, however this code is modifying "one_day" as well @TimRoberts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you do NOT want "the same object" to be assigned to all four keys.  That is the cause of your problem.  When you modify `one_week`, you are modifying that one object (INCLUDING the one referenced in the original `performance` dict), and the change will be seen in all of the keys.

Since you created empty dictionaries for those keys, the easy solution is to use "update" to update the separate empty dictionary ojbects:

```
    if i == 0:
        average_performance['one_day'].update(performance.get(str_today))
        average_performance['one_week'].update(performance.get(str_today))
        average_performance['two_week'].update(performance.get(str_today))
        average_performance['one_month'].update(performance.get(str_today))
        print(average_performance)
```

Comment: Thank you. This works. I still don't understand how this code is different though but thank you for your help.

Comment: I didn't realize that python would modify a variable assigned to another variable after assignment

Comment: You're not thinking about this the right way.  Python has OBJECTS (which are all anonymous), and NAMES (which can be bound to objects).  When you do `performance.get(xxx)`, you are fetching a dictionary OBJECT.  Every time you make that same call, you get the same object.  You then store references to that one object in your four keys.  They keys do not contain independent objects.  They contain references to the one object.  This is a VITAL part of understanding Python.